# Extracting columns by names (matching patterns) in bash

Tags: csv, awk, extract, multiple-columns

```
Coding,Value,Meaning,54-1.0,54-2.0,431-2.0,212-0.0,212-1.0
1,1,Yes,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.6
2,0,Other job (free text entry),0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.8
2,1,Managers and Senior Officials,0.5,0.2,0.4,0.7,0.7
2,11,Corporate Managers,0.1,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.4
2,111,Corporate Managers And Senior Officials,0,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.8
2,1111,Senior officials in national government,0.9,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.9
2,1111001,AM (National Assembly),0.8,0.3,0.2,0,0.2
2,1111002,Ambassador (Foreign and Commonwealth Office),0.9,0.9,0.7,0.1,0.2
2,1111003,Band 0 (Health and Safety Executive),0.6,0.4,0,0.4,0.8
2,1111004,Band 1B (Meteorological Office),0.6,0.1,0.6,1,0.8
```

I have a csv.gz file like above. I want to extract the columns by name that matches certain strings, e.g., columns names matches "54-" and "212-".

I found a solution as below, but I wonder if this can be revised so that it can extract the columns that matches any of the element in a list of strings  e.g., "Meaning", "54-", "212-".

```
zcat test.csv.gz |awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/54-/)f[n++]=i}{for(i=0;i<n;i++)printf"%s%s",i?" ":"",$f[i];print""}'
```

I also want to save this to a csv.gz file. But by adding `> outputfile.csv` at the end, I cannot separate by comma. I wonder where I should put the `OFS=","` in this command?

sample output as below (in a csv.gz file)

```
Meaning,54-1.0,54-2.0,212-0.0,212-1.0
Yes,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.6
Other job (free text entry),0,0.7,0.7,0.8
Managers and Senior Officials,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.7
Corporate Managers,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.4
Corporate Managers And Senior Officials,0,0.8,0.4,0.8
Senior officials in national government,0.9,0.6,0.2,0.9
AM (National Assembly),0.8,0.3,0,0.2
Ambassador (Foreign and Commonwealth Office),0.9,0.9,0.1,0.2
Band 0 (Health and Safety Executive),0.6,0.4,0.4,0.8
Band 1B (Meteorological Office),0.6,0.1,1,0.8
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post expected sample output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Where are the commas in your CSV file?

Comment: the example is reformated. sorry for being unclear

Comment: on a side note, you don't need to pipe. just go with `awk -F, 'doodley doo' test.csv.gz`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hope this helps change variable `get` according to your need:*

**One-liner:**

```
$ awk -v get='^(Meaning|54-|212-)' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~get)cols[++c]=i}{for(i=1; i<=c; i++)printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<c ? OFS : ORS)}' file
Meaning,54-1.0,54-2.0,212-0.0,212-1.0
Yes,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.6
Other job (free text entry),0,0.7,0.7,0.8
Managers and Senior Officials,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.7
Corporate Managers,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.4
Corporate Managers And Senior Officials,0,0.8,0.4,0.8
Senior officials in national government,0.9,0.6,0.2,0.9
AM (National Assembly),0.8,0.3,0,0.2
Ambassador (Foreign and Commonwealth Office),0.9,0.9,0.1,0.2
Band 0 (Health and Safety Executive),0.6,0.4,0.4,0.8
Band 1B (Meteorological Office),0.6,0.1,1,0.8
```

**In your case :**

```
$ zcat test.csv.gz | awk -v get='^(Meaning|54-|212-)' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~get)cols[++c]=i}{for(i=1; i<=c; i++)printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<c ? OFS : ORS)}'
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk -v get='^(Meaning|54-|212-)' '
         BEGIN{
             FS=OFS=","
         }
         FNR==1{
               for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                   if($i~get)cols[++c]=i
         }
         {
           for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
                printf "%s%s", $(cols[i]), (i<c ? OFS : ORS)
         }' file
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat file
Coding,Value,Meaning,54-1.0,54-2.0,431-2.0,212-0.0,212-1.0
1,1,Yes,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.6
2,0,Other job (free text entry),0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.8
2,1,Managers and Senior Officials,0.5,0.2,0.4,0.7,0.7
2,11,Corporate Managers,0.1,0.7,0.4,0.2,0.4
2,111,Corporate Managers And Senior Officials,0,0.8,0.8,0.4,0.8
2,1111,Senior officials in national government,0.9,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.9
2,1111001,AM (National Assembly),0.8,0.3,0.2,0,0.2
2,1111002,Ambassador (Foreign and Commonwealth Office),0.9,0.9,0.7,0.1,0.2
2,1111003,Band 0 (Health and Safety Executive),0.6,0.4,0,0.4,0.8
2,1111004,Band 1B (Meteorological Office),0.6,0.1,0.6,1,0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` script with explanation.

Notice line #3 it defines list of fields identifiers in `fieldsIdentifierList` variable, you can modify it.
Or use as an external input variable using `-v` command line option.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN { # pre process initial values
  OFS = ","; # set output separator to ","
  fieldsIdentifierList = "54-,212-,Meaning"; # list field identifiers
  split(fieldsIdentifierList, fieldsIdentifierArr, ","); # create an array from field identifiers
}
NR == 1 { # process only the first line
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) # for each field
    for(fieldIdentifier in fieldsIdentifierArr) { # and for each field identifiers
      if($i ~ fieldsIdentifierArr[fieldIdentifier]) { # if field match field identifier
        targetFieldsArr[++n]=i; # append field idx to target fields array
      }
    }
}
{ # for each line
  for(field in targetFieldsArr) # for each target field
    printf("%s%s", field > 1? OFS: "", $targetFieldsArr[field]); # print the target field followed by field separatorfollowed by field separator
  print ""; # print end of line.
}
```

#### running `script.awk`

```
zcat test.csv.gz |awk -f script.awk
```

#### sample output

```
$ awk -f script.awk input.txt
Meaning,54-1.0,54-2.0,212-0.0,212-1.0
Yes,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.6
Other,job,(free,entry),0.0
Managers,and,Senior,0.5,0.2
Corporate,Managers,0.1,0.4,0.2
Corporate,Managers,And,Officials,0.0
Senior,officials,in,government,0.9
AM,(National,Assembly),0.3,0.2
Ambassador,(Foreign,and,Office),0.9
Band,0,(Health,Safety,Executive)
Band,1B,(Meteorological,0.6,0.1
```

@ Dudi Boy, I got something like this using the above script

```
Coding  Value   Meaning 54-1.0  54-2.0  431-2.0 212-0.0 212-1.0 
    Coding  Value   Meaning 54-1.0  54-2.0  431-2.0 212-0.0 212-1.0
    Coding  Value   Meaning 54-1.0  54-2.0  431-2.0 212-0.0 212-1.0
1   1   Yes 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.1 0.6 
    1   1   Yes 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.1 0.6
    1   1   Yes 0.4 0.3 0.7 0.1 0.6
2   0   Other   2   0   Other   2   0   Other
2   1   Managers    2   1   Managers    2   1   Managers
2   11  Corporate   2   11  Corporate   2   11  Corporate
2   111 Corporate   2   111 Corporate   2   111 Corporate
2   1111    Senior  2   1111    Senior  2   1111    Senior
2   1111001 AM  2   1111001 AM  2   1111001 AM
2   1111002 Ambassador  2   1111002 Ambassador  2   1111002 Ambassador
2   1111003 Band    2   1111003 Band    2   1111003 Band
2   1111004 Band    2   1111004 Band    2   1111004 Band
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I cannot get the output. I got a messy csv file with duplicate columns and records.